# Loading data with sharedPreferences in my setSingleChoiceItems alertdialog

Tags: android, radio-button, sharedpreferences, android-alertdialog

I'm saving the language the user selected in a `setSingleChoiceItems alertDialog`. I'd like that when the app starts that everything is displayed in the correct langauge and also when a user wants to select a new language, that when he presses the listView to get the alertdialog that he gets to see the already chosen language by the right radiobutton that's been selected. But I can't seem to load the data. In the onCreate I'm calling my function `LoadPrefs();` But that doesn't seem to do the trick. So I guess I'm doing something wrong here?

Is it also possible to Load the data in my starting activity, because I'm saving a language preferences and it should change directly when the app opens and not when the user gets to `SettingsActivity`

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {        

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        LoadPrefs();
        registerClickCallBack();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settingsList);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Language", "Facebook login", "About" };

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void LoadPrefs(){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String langValue = sp.getString("lang", "en");      

    }

    private void savePrefs(String lang, String value){
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor edit = sp.edit();
        edit.putString(lang, value);
        edit.commit();
    }

    private String lang(String lang){
        String language = lang;
        Locale local;
        Configuration config;

        local = new Locale(language); 
        Locale.setDefault(local);
        config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = local;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        savePrefs("lang", lang);

        return lang;    
    }


    private void registerClickCallBack() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.settingsList);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                    int position, long id) {

                if (position == 0) {                    
                    String langEN = getResources().getString(R.string.langEN);
                    String langFR = getResources().getString(R.string.langFR);
                    String langNL = getResources().getString(R.string.langNL);
                    String langTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.langTitle);

                    final CharSequence[] items = {langEN, langFR, langNL};

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle(langTitle);

                    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                            switch (item) {
                                case 0:
                                    lang("en");
                                    break;

                                case 1:
                                    lang("fr");
                                    break;

                                case 2:
                                    lang("nl");
                                    break;

                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();


                        }
                    });

                    final AlertDialog levelDialog = builder.create();
                    levelDialog.show();

                }
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Comment: Instead of using PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); use getSharedPreferences("Pref_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Where should I do this? And what is the difference? Can you give me some more info please? **EDIT** Just done this in the settingsactivity and this didn't change anything for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

First of all, you have to apply your custom configuration(s) before setting content view.

That's in your code's context, call `LoadPrefs()` prior to `setContentView()` and add `lang(langValue);` to the end of it.

Second, you have to restart your app after user chooses new locale. You can accomplish this with something like this (there could be other/better ways though):

```
private void restartSelf() {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + 1000/*restart after one second*/,
    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, getIntent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));
    finish();
}
```

Note: I see you are using English, Dutch and German languages all of which are natively supported by the OS. You would better of if you use platform provided [localization](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

Comment: I've added an answer with log output and more information, please check that out.